# Sound libraries similar to Blastdrive or Sound Ideas?

Tags: sound-libraries

I'm looking for newer libraries like [Blastdrive](http://www.blastwavefx.com/p2/The%20BLASTDRIVE%202.0%20HD%20Sound%20Effects%20Library/product_info.html) or the new Sound Ideas [General HD Collection](http://www.sound-ideas.com/general-hd-sfx.html) that provide a wide range of general content @ 96k 24bit.

Comment: take a look at this thread.  I think it covers some of what you are looking for.
http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/8857/how-does-the-new-general-hd-library-from-sound-ideas-compare-to-the-old-school-ge